# Error: non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, server, shiny, selectinput

Good Day, making application in RStudio/Shiny is very new to me and I am working with a project in  which an external file is to be used as the input data. Here is my CSV: [image: Click to see: Wattage of an Appliance]

my supposed to be app:

[image: Click to see: calculator to compute electric bill]

So the user insert a csv with appliance name in row 1 and their wattage in row 2 just like in the picture above, then the selectInput will be updated. The user choose what appliance and hours of usage then it will be calculated for its cost

Here is my server code:

```
server <- function(input,output,session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$file1, {
    
    mytable <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
    
    updateSelectInput(session, "select", "Appliances", 
                      choices = colnames(mytable))
    
  })
  
  dataset_day <- reactive ({
    costday <- ((input$select * input$hour) / 1000) * 8.9535
    costday <- data.frame(costday)
    names(costday)  <- "Electricity Cost per day (Philippine Peso)"
    print(costday)
  })
  
  dataset_month <- reactive ({
    costmonth <- (((input$select * input$hour) / 1000) * 8.9535) * 30
    costmonth <- data.frame(costmonth)
    names(costmonth)  <- "Electricity Cost per month (Philippine Peso)"
    print(costmonth)
  })
```

I need help in putting the value written in the CSV of the chosen appliance by the user to the equation.

In short how to fix the non-numeric argument to binary operator error.

I think the error is in the input$select but I am lost about this.

```
((input$select * input$hour) / 1000) * 8.9535
```

Do I need to change or add something in order to fix this? Is this app possible to do? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

This utterly non-descriptive error message is totally spot on, when you understand this backwards non-message:

You are trying to do math with something that is not numbers.

In this case, you are probably correct in that it occurs in `input$select * input$hour`, because either or both are probably characters. On the HTML side of your app, there are no numbers in the values. Only strings. So what do we get back?

Try inserting the Best Debugging Tool known to programmer: print-statements. Here, try simply adding an observer e.g.:

```
observe({
  cat('This is observer\n')
  str(input$select)
  str(input$hour)
})
```

You should now see something in your console like this:

```
This is observer
  chr "Bulb"
  num 12.0
```

or

```
This is observer
  chr "11"
  num 12.0
```

What does this imply? That `input$select` is *not* numeric, but a character string.

Solution: Convert it to numeric with e.g. `as.numeric` (latter case), or map it to something numeric (former case).

Comment: Good Day Sir, can the values or the numbers in the csv below the appliance name be used to map it to something numeric? If so how, I am so sorry I am still a newbie in programming and thank you for understanding.                                                                               If the user chooses bulb the server would use the value 11 in the csv as the numeric value and solves it like that. Is it possible?

Comment: or something like if the user chooses bulb, a numericInput box will show the number 11 as based on the csv making it a numeric value.

Comment: What a brave, young noob, attempting 3 *new* things at once! But you are not fruitless. For the input from csv, you must deconstruct your commands. I.e. consider the output from `mytable <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath); colnames(mytable)` and compare this to the input required for `selectInput` and `updateSelectInput`. Additionally, in the app's current state, inspect the generated html in a browser (with "Inspect elements"). Now compare it with what you gave it.

Comment: Finally, try to look through the examples for `updateSelectInput` and see how you can create a vector, that can display one set of values to the user, and returns a different set of values to code (effectively the first and second row of `mytable`).